# Why I'm not getting scrape data by using my method?

Tags: web-scraping, data-analysis

I used BeautifulSoup. there are 600 + products but I'm only getting 9. Can you please help me to get all the data?
I'm also sharing code for reference

```
for i in range (1,64):
url = 'https://www.lenskart.com/eyeglasses/marketing/vc-air-bestseller-eyeglasses.html?page=' +str(i)
r =requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")

Model = []
Size = []
Rating = []
Price = []

P_Name = soup.find_all('div',class_="product-name")

for i in P_Name:
    name = i.text
    Model.append(name)

P_size = soup.find_all('span',class_="tags")

for i in P_size:
    name = i.text
    Size.append(name)   

P_rating = soup.find_all('span',class_="rating-value")

for i in P_rating:
    name = i.text
    Rating.append(name)

P_price = soup.find_all('span',class_="text-color-dark-blue fw700")

for i in P_price:
    name = i.text
    Price.append(name)
```

Comment: I wish you scraping people would learn how to spell scrape.

Comment: You must share the complete code, so we can help you.

Comment: I did changes, please check. I'm using stackoverflow first time.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the url in a browser, scroll down a bit and watch the scroll bar on the right. You'll probably notice it moving down as you scroll, but jumping about (up and down) as you do so.

Also note the size of the bar as you keep scrolling down. You should see it becoming shorter.

Whet this means is that as you scroll, it dynamically loads more products to add at the end of the current list.

I see that you have a ?page= parameter to the url. I'd guess that the site has 9 products per page but on scrolling down will async load the next page. I guess you'll have load pages individually until you get a result with no products loaded, showing (probably) that you're at the end.

This is all a guess, but without more investigation or information from you, I don't think much more can be done.

HTH!